# How can I make my Game Maker Studio 2 project run properly on an Android Emulator?

Tags: android-studio, game-maker, haxm, game-maker-studio-2

I have been trying to test my gms2 project on an android emulator from android studio.  I first set up the sdk, using this article as a guide https:
//help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001368727-Setting-Up-For-Android-or-Amazon-Fire
Then, I used this article:
https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000270191-Android-Setting-Up-Virtual-Devices
to set up virtual android devices.  One thing I did note when doing this was that the HAXM installer failed every time, this is what I saw

```
For more details, please check the installation log: C:\Users\GRAHAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_install-20210917_0928.log
Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows
Done
```

This is what I saw on the SDK manager
[image: picture of window]

This may be related, I'm not sure.  But then, I went into gms2 and followed everything in the articles, but when I tried to run the project, I got the following output:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String )
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Int32 , String , String , String[] )
   at GMAssetCompiler.WADSaver`1.<>c.(KeyValuePair`2 )
   at GMAssetCompiler.Program..(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String )
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Int32 , String , String , String[] )
   at GMAssetCompiler.WADSaver`1.<>c.(KeyValuePair`2 )
   at GMAssetCompiler.Program..(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String )
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Int32 , String , String , String[] )
   at GMAssetCompiler.WADSaver`1.<>c.(KeyValuePair`2 )
   at GMAssetCompiler.Program..(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String )
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Int32 , String , String , String[] )
   at GMAssetCompiler.WADSaver`1.<>c.(KeyValuePair`2 )
   at GMAssetCompiler.Program..(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String )
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Int32 , String , String , String[] )
   at GMAssetCompiler.WADSaver`1.<>c.(KeyValuePair`2 )
   at GMAssetCompiler.Program..(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String )
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Int32 , String , String , String[] )
   at GMAssetCompiler.WADSaver`1.<>c.(KeyValuePair`2 )
   at GMAssetCompiler.Program..(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String )
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Int32 , String , String , String[] )
   at GMAssetCompiler.WADSaver`1.<>c.(KeyValuePair`2 )
   at GMAssetCompiler.Program..(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String )
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Int32 , String , String , String[] )
   at GMAssetCompiler.WADSaver`1.<>c.(KeyValuePair`2 )
   at GMAssetCompiler.Program..(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXCEPTION FILE - C:\Users\GRAHAMJT20\AppData\Local\Temp\a839beeab34845389c4d01131e83e7cd.yyg.saencryptedreport
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXCEPTION FILE - C:\Users\GRAHAMJT20\AppData\Local\Temp\02db8f82f77e49a5a8414617cce166e6.yyg.saencryptedreport
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXCEPTION FILE - C:\Users\GRAHAMJT20\AppData\Local\Temp\b040736233304be79cc6c2d2c53ad089.yyg.saencryptedreport
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXCEPTION FILE - C:\Users\GRAHAMJT20\AppData\Local\Temp\27f7125ae7a047debcc5b7463282ace9.yyg.saencryptedreport
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXCEPTION FILE - C:\Users\GRAHAMJT20\AppData\Local\Temp\ef897878cf614509afbba924f24b0806.yyg.saencryptedreport
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXCEPTION FILE - C:\Users\GRAHAMJT20\AppData\Local\Temp\bcd410e5ac854919bb7b9486c6f6866c.yyg.saencryptedreport
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXCEPTION FILE - C:\Users\GRAHAMJT20\AppData\Local\Temp\5f27bb810dc041b9b7b79c4c98eab7ed.yyg.saencryptedreport
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String )
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Int32 , String , String , String[] )
   at GMAssetCompiler.WADSaver`1.<>c.(KeyValuePair`2 )
   at GMAssetCompiler.Program..(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String )
   at GMAssetCompiler.TexturePage.(String , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Boolean , Int32 , String , String , String[] )
   at GMAssetCompiler.WADSaver`1.<>c.(KeyValuePair`2 )
   at GMAssetCompiler.Program..(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

This is all a bit over my head to be honest.  Any help getting this to work would be appreciated.
(There was more to the error output that I can provide if needed, it was too long to put here though)

Comment: Install the newest haxm (HAXM v7.7.0 at github.com/intel/haxm/releases). If any issues will occur during installation, HAXM installer will show a detailed output of what exactly failed.

Comment: @nevilad I tried this, and the installer ran without issue.  I am able to open an android virtual device without issue.  The problem is once it is open and I build the gms2 project for testing on android, I get the above error.

Comment: For anyone seeing this in the future, I have since discovered the issue.  At the time of this post, it seems GMS2 only works for testing with Android Studio 4.2.0.  I went back and installed this from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive , and this fixed my issue.  I can test now.